# Automatically subscribe to Facebook page

Tags: facebook-application

I have two company facebook pages. We do same industry, just slightly different. Thus we have two company pages. Lets call them Apage and Bpage.

I want to automatically post content that is published on Apage to Bpage, something like subscription if you will. Are there ways in FB API, or these are uncharted waters?

Answer (score 1):

No There is not a Native solution to this.

However, you can achieve it by using Third Party Social Media Management tools. 
They allow you to add multiple accounts of different Network, schedule and post the content.

HootSuite is an example (I'm not affiliated with them.)

Comment: It seems Hootsuite has more tools then I need. I will check it and postback the results :)

Comment: and its free upto 5 accounts :-)